# Create an array from a remote XML for android

Tags: android, xml, arrays, sax

I have a remote XML file I want to use to populate a listview.

I have the app set up currently to create a listview from a local array. How do I populate the array using an XML file stored online? The array is currently located in strings.xml

```
public class ArchiveListActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.archivetitle, R.layout.archiveitem));

    final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.archivelinks);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String content = links[position];
            Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ArchiveViewerActivity.class);
            showContent.setData(Uri.parse(content));
            startActivity(showContent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it in the below mentioned steps:

1> Prepare the request URI where the xml is present.

```
prepareRequestUrl();
```

2> Get the response from the web-server:

```
/** 
 * fetch the response for the request url
 * @param request url string
 * @return InputStream
 */
public InputStream getResponse(String reqUrl) throws AppException {

    URL                 url             =   null;
    URLConnection       connection      =   null;
    HttpURLConnection   httpConnection  =   null;
    int                 reponseCode     =   0;
    InputStream         inputStream     =   null;

    try {

        url = new URL(reqUrl);

        connection = url.openConnection();

        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

        reponseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    if (reponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        try {

            inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    else    {
        throw new AppException(AppConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_FAILURE);
    }

    return inputStream;
}
```

3> Parse the input stream xml received from the server:

```
                   inputStream = super.getResponse(requestUrl);             
        result= xmlParser.parseList(inputStream);
```

4> Show the corresponding result in a listview.

Note: Its always recommended to use an async task to do any network operation.here in this case invoking the we-server.

Hope this helps!